Where is the property 'arm-smmuv3.stage' to support stage-2 translation in qemu?
I learned from QEMU's changeLog that QEMU now has the option to support SMMUv3's stage 2 translation, but I'm not sure how to enable the system property 'arm-smmuv3.stage' mentioned here. Where is this parameter, in the boot arguments?
I've tried adding this parameter in the machine, but it failed.

I'm sorry that the pictures are lost because of unknown reason.The property is appeared in this article: https://patchew.org/QEMU/20230516203327.2051088-1-smostafa@google.com.

This property isn't a user-facing one you can change on the command line. It's available for a board model which wants it to select stage2 translation instead of stage1, when it creates the SMMU as part of creating and wiring up all the devices on the board. (At the moment no upstream board models use this.)
